# jQuery does not work in IE11, but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have problem with jQuery. When I upload image in Chrome it performs the AJAX successfully and I am able to update the page with the response data. But in IE 11 and Firefox it does not. The code:

```
$(".newfoto").on('submit', (function(e) {
    $("#mailresult").html('<img src="themes/standart/iconss/spin1.gif" alt="loading..." /><p>Please, wait...</p>');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "dataok.php?act=foto",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#mailresult").html(data);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#mailresult").empty();
            }, 2000);
            var imgTag = '<img src="image.php?imgid=' + escape($('.myphoto').attr('id')) + '" />';
            $('.myphoto').html(imgTag);
        },

        error: function() {}

    });
}));
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately to make it readable.  You need both proper indentation and to get rid of the double spacing.

Comment: @jfriend00 which double spacing? I could not understand. sorry

Comment: The code in your question has a blank line between nearly every actual line of code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I edited the code. You meaned this ?

Comment: Yes, that removed all the extra blank lines.  As I said in my first comment, please add proper indentation too.  If you don't know what I mean, then paste your code into here: http://jsbeautifier.org/ and and press the beautify button.

Comment: @jfriend00 , ok, I beautified it. But there is no change. It does not work

Comment: It looks OK to me. Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar , No, all javascripts work fine. This code also work fine in Chrome. But not in IE 11 and Firefox

Comment: If you put an `alert()` in the function, do you see the alert?

Comment: FYI, `escape()` has been deprecated.  You should be using `encodeURIComponent()` instead.

Comment: Is the code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Is the page getting reloaded in IE11 and Firefox?

Comment: @jfriend00 , ok. I will try. Barmar , yes it is inside document.ready

Comment: @jfriend00 I changed escape() to encodeURIComponent(). No, the page does not reload in any browser .

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with the `FormData` support in different browsers.  That object is only partially implemented in Firefox and IE.  Try changing: `data: new FormData(this),` to `data: $(this).serialize(),`.

Comment: No , it does not help. The problem is not in form data. Because form data successfully uploads image. The problem is in var img Tag or html(imgTag). May be I must change one of them

Comment: -3 for the code and no solution :)). Life is very cruel

Comment: donot take downvote personally.it's not aimed at you it's for the betterness of the question and answer both which is objective of SO.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to prevent the form from submitting and reloading the page is to use a `return false;` at the end of the submit function. This will also replace `e.preventDefault();` in your code.

Also, `FormData` is not supported on all browsers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2320097/584192. You may need to detect and workaround this.

```
$(".newfoto").on('submit', function(e) {
    $("#mailresult").html('<img src="themes/standart/iconss/spin1.gif" alt="loading..." /><p>Please, wait...</p>');
    $.ajax({
        url: "dataok.php?act=foto",
        type: "POST",
        data: (typeof FormData === 'function') ? new FormData(this) : $(this).serialize(),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // success
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: var imgTag = '<img src="image.php?imgid=' + escape($('.myphoto').attr('id')) + '" />';
            $('.myphoto').html(imgTag);     // The problem is in these lines. May be I can change it, but how ?